# can't connect to MySQL on localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using the code below, but my attempt fails.

This is my attempt:

```
private static Connection conn = null;
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
private static String dbName = "proj1";
private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String userName = "root";
private static String password = "root";

public static  int setupConnection ()
{
    try{
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,"root","root");
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When installing MySQL, I remember entering the password "root", but I'm not 100% sure if the username is automatically assigned "root".

I get the error message : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: usually mysql connections come on 3306 port. try in the `url`. Try `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";`
And yes, mysql comes automatically with "root" user

Comment: @AndreiSfat The MySQL JDBC driver defaults to 3306 if not specified

Comment: @Andrei Sfat i tried it , no luck , im thinking this has something to do with mysql connector

Comment: Okay, then as @DaDaDom said, what is the error message? Did you include the connector jar?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a likely error message. Was there a mistake in editing your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the MySQL Connector/J driver to the build-path/classpath of your Netbeans project. Otherwise it cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not mention what kind of failure you got. 
But here are some tips.

My JDBC URL looks like the following. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYSCHEMA`. So port and schema name are missing in yours.

To check your credentials try to connect to your DB using command line client:

`mysql -uroot -proot`

Read the error message if you fail. If you cannot restore credentials, re-install MySql. It takes 3 minutes. Do not try to connect to DB using your code unless you can do it using existing clients.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you should connect to port address 3306,
change the url as below :

```
private static  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
```

I am considering that you are not getting any compilation error and you have added mysql java api..

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying to log into mysql from a command shell.  If you can't, JDBC won't be able to, either.

This might help if you can't remember:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html