# Accessing phpMyAdmin database though Java

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to access phpMyAdmin data base from java plug-in project.
I have added mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar to the external jar files of  the project and following is the connection string I use to access the database:

```
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
String link= "jdbc:odbc:https://just36.justhost.com:2083:databaseName=xxxx";
private static String userName = "xxxx";
private static String password = "xxxx";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(link, userName, password);
```

The URL, database name, username and password are correct. But this code gives following error.

---

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at vocab.ITSVocabulary.ReadTextInput(ITSVocabulary.java:27)

### at vocab.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:23)

**Line 27: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);**

I checked the related posts to this problem and set the classpath variable for this JAR file too.
Before this, I tried mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.jar, it also didn't work.
Do I need to set any class paths, or change any network setting here?
I'm really grateful if someone can tell me is there anything wrong with this procedure or what I missed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why it is phpmyadmin? phpmyadmin is nothing, but just a client for mysql, state it like connect java to mysql. User google to search for this, You will find tons of blogs explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

Why it is phpmyadmin? phpmyadmin is nothing, but just a client for mysql, state the title like connect java to mysql. Use google to search for this, You will find tons of blogs explaining this. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576856/cant-connect-to-mysql-on-localhost) should be fine for you

Answer (score 1):

```
final String server="localhost/";

final String db_name="db_name";

final String userName="xxxx";

final String password="xxxx";

Connection myConn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+server+db_name,userName,password);
```

Comment: Please format your answer and provide information, how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a mysql connect string but an odbc one. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Also it would be a mysql database not phpmyadmin, the latter is a PHP UI for mysql